# Getting NotFoundHttpException for my edit route

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

This is my route

```
Route::get(
   'account-executive/{$id}/edit', 
    array(
        'as'   => 'vendor-edit',
        'uses' => 'AdminController@updateVendor'
    )
);
```

This is my method

```
public function updateVendor($id)
{
    $vendor = Vendor::findOrFail($id);

    return View::make('admin.edit-account-executive');
}
```

I keep getting  NotFoundHttpException. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: what url are you trying to access ?

Comment: site.com/account-executive/1/edit

Comment: Use {id} instead of {$id} in your get route.

Answer (score 3):

Your route definition isn't correct.

```
 Route::get('account-executive/{$id}/edit', array('as' => 'vendor-edit','uses' => 'AdminController@updateVendor'));
```

You don't need a `$` sign in definition of route parameter. So you should just write `account-executive/{id}/edit`.

Try it.